# p parsed["desc"]["someKey"], in ruby what does "p" mean?

Tags: ruby

```
# JSON Parsing example
require "rubygems"
require "json"

string = '{"desc":{"someKey":"someValue","anotherKey":"value"},"main_item":{"stats":{"a":8,"b":12,"c":10}}}'
parsed = JSON.parse(string) # returns a hash

p parsed["desc"]["someKey"]
p parsed["main_item"]["stats"]["a"]

# Read JSON from a file, iterate over objects
file = open("shops.json")
json = file.read

parsed = JSON.parse(json)

parsed["shop"].each do |shop|
  p shop["id"]
end
```

is that predict?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) method.

According to the documentation:

> ```
> p(obj) → obj click to toggle source
> p(obj1, obj2, ...) → [obj, ...]
> p() → nil
> ```
>
> For each object, directly writes obj.inspect followed by a newline to
>   the program’s standard output.